# Do we want to unpin the accepted answer from the top?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

**[Stack Overflow has changed the way the answers are sorted:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/967621)**

> We no longer pin the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) to the top of the list of answers. By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score.

**There is [a question now on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/578690) if we would like to have the accepted answer unpinned on our site:**

> We can change the way the engine sorts answers in site settings. We would like to hear from you all if it is something you want to see on your site. [...] **We are going to collect feedback before the end of September 19th.**

*I am posting this question here to discuss what would work best for is here at Gardening Stack Exchange.*

Just a few numbers for you:

Out of the 16k questions on the site, we currently have 431 posts (so well under 3%) where the accepted answer has fewer votes than the highest answer. In the majority of all these cases, the difference is one or two votes.

The posts with the highest difference are:

- [Is this orange-yellowish-flowered plant a wildflower or a weed?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/40938)
- [How do I remove weeds and prevent them growing between the bricks in a paved area?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4682)
- [Will dumping paint destroy a nearby tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/300)

Answer (score 2):

I am not experienced enough, still I am sharing my thoughts.

I would like to see the current format of sorting answers, i.e., accepted answer pinned at the top and then the rest of the answers sorted according to the votes.

> Why?

Suppose there are 20 answers for a question. We will think of two situations.

1. where the accepted answer has votes equal or near to the most voted answer
2. where the accepted answer has the lowest vote or near the low scored ones

**Now, if the accepted answer is unpinned,**

In CASE:1, the accepted answer as well as the higher voted answers will be easier to find.

In CASE:2, the accepted answer will get lost among the answers (even though it had worked out for the OP)

For this I think the present format is best, where you can find the accepted answer at the top and the other answers organised orderly according to the votes (so that you know what the community thinks the solution to the problem is).